# WPF use touch for RadioButton

Tags: wpf, radio-button, touch

I'm using RadioButton on a WPF/C# on a parameter view. I want the user to choose only 1 option, so I use RadioButton and GroupName. It works fine, but it only react to click event, not touch...

Is there a way to have touch event to control my buttons or do I have to redefine all the default comportment of a RadioButton with touchDown event ?

Here are my radioButtons, even if I don't think they are usefull for my problem

```
<Viewbox Height="50">
    <RadioButton x:Name="imposerOrdreHaut" Content="Avec" IsChecked="True" GroupName="ordre" Padding="2"  Checked="RadioButtonChecked" />
</Viewbox>
<Viewbox Height="50">
    <RadioButton  Content="Sans" GroupName="ordre" Padding="2" Checked="RadioButtonChecked" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it using a touchDown event who switch "IsChecked=true", and it automatically switch false other buttons